# Getting Dates by Selecting a week in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have a textbox with random numbers from 1 to 52 which are week numbers of a calendar and a drop down which mentions as years.

For example if I select 2 in a textbox with year 2014, then I want the dates to be mentioned as `05-1-2014` - `11-1-2014`. Is it possible to do it.

Also I have tried one query which doesnt match my requirement

```
SELECT date_val, TO_CHAR (date_val, 'ww')
  FROM (SELECT     TO_DATE ('01-jan-2013', 'DD-MON-YYYY') + LEVEL AS date_val
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Here `2` is the number of week in the year (`FirstSunday+(NumberOfWeek-1)*7 as WeekStart, FirstSunday+ NumberOfWeek*7-1 as WeekEnd`) and `2014` is a year:

```
select 
       FirstSunday+(2-1)*7 as WeekStart,
       FirstSunday+ 2*7-1 as WeekEnd    

from 
(
Select NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE('01/01/'||'2014','DD/MM/YYYY')-7, 'SUN')  as FirstSunday 
       from dual
)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/21916)</kbd>

Comment: I had one more doubt,In this query, only start date and end date is shown, is it possible to display all the days of the week?

Comment: @user2357418: `FirstSunday+(2-1)*7+1 as Mon,FirstSunday+(2-1)*7+2 as Tue,FirstSunday+(2-1)*7+3 as Wed,....`

Answer (score 0):

Try this too,

```
SELECT start_date, 
       start_date + 6 end_day
FROM(
     SELECT TRUNC(Trunc(to_date('2014', 'YYYY'),'YYYY')+ 1 * 7,'IW')-1 start_date 
     FROM duaL
     );
```